# password management on FBA SP2007

Tags: 2007, forms-authentication

Is there any form of password management with forms based authentication, like password reset or someone managing it centrally?
This is SP2007

Answer (score 0):

The Community Kit for SharePoint includes these features for SharePoint 2007.

http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/17901